# How to create a button on a field in QWizardPage

Tags: python, pyside2

I am attempting to create a field in a QWizardPage that the user can either click on and a popup window opens up (this would be a window with a map on that allows the user to pick 2 coordinates) or allows the user to input the coordinates themselves. Think along the lines of a file picker line where the user can either open the popup file browser or manually type in the file path.

The original command is QLineEdit.

Comment: I should have noted that I am using PySide2 for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom widget that for example shows a QDoubleSpinBox for latitude and another for longitude, in addition to a button that allows to display a map (for example using QML). And then the widget is added to QWizardPage like any other widget.

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtCore import Property, Signal, Slot, Qt, QUrl
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QDialogButtonBox,
    QDoubleSpinBox,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QToolButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QWizard,
    QWizardPage,
)
from PyQt5.QtPositioning import QGeoCoordinate
from PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


class MapDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, geo_widget):
        super().__init__(geo_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Map")
        self.map_widget = QQuickWidget(resizeMode=QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView)
        self.map_widget.rootContext().setContextProperty("controller", geo_widget)
        filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
        self.map_widget.setSource(url)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox()
        button_box.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        button_box.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.map_widget)
        lay.addWidget(button_box)

        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)


class GeoWidget(QWidget):
    coordinate_changed = Signal(name="coordinateChanged")

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._coordinate = QGeoCoordinate(0, 0)

        self._lat_spinbox = QDoubleSpinBox(
            minimum=-90.0, maximum=90.0, valueChanged=self.handle_value_changed
        )
        self._lng_spinbox = QDoubleSpinBox(
            minimum=-180.0, maximum=180.0, valueChanged=self.handle_value_changed
        )
        self.btn = QToolButton(text="map", clicked=self.handle_clicked)
        self.map_view = MapDialog(self)

        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QLabel("Latitude:"))
        lay.addWidget(self._lat_spinbox)
        lay.addWidget(QLabel("Longitude:"))
        lay.addWidget(self._lng_spinbox)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)

    @Property(QGeoCoordinate, notify=coordinate_changed)
    def coordinate(self):
        return self._coordinate

    @coordinate.setter
    def coordinate(self, coordinate):
        if self.coordinate == coordinate:
            return
        self._coordinate = coordinate
        self.coordinate_changed.emit()

    def handle_value_changed(self):
        coordinate = QGeoCoordinate(
            self._lat_spinbox.value(), self._lng_spinbox.value()
        )
        self.coordinate = coordinate

    @Slot(QGeoCoordinate)
    def update_from_map(self, coordinate):
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self._lat_spinbox.setValue(self.coordinate.latitude())
        self._lng_spinbox.setValue(self.coordinate.longitude())

    def handle_clicked(self):
        self.map_view.exec_()


class WizardPage(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geo_widget1 = GeoWidget()
        self.geo_widget2 = GeoWidget()

        self.registerField("coordinate1", self.geo_widget1, b"coordinate")
        self.registerField("coordinate2", self.geo_widget2, b"coordinate")

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.geo_widget1)
        lay.addWidget(self.geo_widget2)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWizard()
    page = WizardPage()
    w.addPage(page)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Map {
        id: map

        anchors.fill: parent
        zoomLevel: 14

        MouseArea {
            id: mouse
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: controller.update_from_map(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)))
        }

        plugin: Plugin {
            name: "osm"
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Will this also work with PySide2 instead of PyQt5?